# How to all messages on Azure Storage Queue without dequeuing in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-queues

I have an Azure Storage Queue and want to create a service to view the contents of for admin-purposes. I know I can view the queue using Storage Explorer, but I want to be able to view the messages (and their contents) in a C# application.

From what I can see, the API allows me to get the write to and pop from the head of the queue, but I need to see all messages without removing them.

Comment: There's [peek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/peek-messages) bu that just lets you see 32 messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is [PeekMessagesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient.peekmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet), with that you can peek the first X messages in the queue. Example:

```
// Create a QueueClient.
var queueClient = new QueueClient("your-storage-account", "your-queue-name");

// Peek at the first 32 messages in the queue.
var messages = await queueClient.PeekMessagesAsync(32);
```

Next you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: `PeekMessagesAsync` is for Service Bus queues, not Storage queues.

Answer (score 1):

try using the following code:

```
public static class DryRunIterator
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> GetMessages(string connectionString, string queueName, int prefetchCount)
    {
        await using var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

        await using var deadLetterReceiver = serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions() { PrefetchCount = prefetchCount, ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock });
        long? lastReceivedSequenceNumber = null;

        while (true)
        {
            var messages = await deadLetterReceiver.PeekMessagesAsync(prefetchCount, lastReceivedSequenceNumber + 1);

            if (messages.Count == 0)
                break;

            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                yield return message;

                lastReceivedSequenceNumber = message.SequenceNumber;
            }
        }

        await deadLetterReceiver.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

it uses `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using `Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient` which, it turns out, also has a PeekMessagesAsync method. Thanks!